# "from which this town was created" or "from which this town was created out of"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, prepositional-phrases

I have a phrase "which indicates the city from which this town was created". The idea is that the town was created from, or out of (carved from) the city. I am not sure if this is grammatically correct. I was also thinking maybe "which indicates the city from which this town was created out of". Kindly help.

Comment: Also, is "which indicates the city out of which this town was created" correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your construction contains an example of *pied-piping* whereby the preposition (in this case, either *from* or *out of*) moves in front of the relative pronoun:

> - ...the city *from* which this town was created
> - ...the city *out of* which this town was created

This is a more formal usage than the alternative, which is called *preposition stranding*:

> - ...the city (which) this town was created *from*
> - ...the city  (which) this town was created *out of*

From this it should be clear that the construction *...the city *from* which this town was created *out of** contains both pied-piping and preposition stranding - one of which is redundant.

In summary, if you are aiming for more formal language, then pied-pipe the preposition, otherwise strand it. As to which preposition to use, it's difficult to say which is better without knowing the full sentence.

There is an explanation of this topic on *[ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/pied-piping-syntax-1691627)*.